# Have Ctrl-Right move Caret to Word end instead of String end (configure caret stop)

Tags: google-chrome, textbox, caret

I googled everywhere, but seem not to find how to make Chrome behave like Internet Explorer on this.

I want to make Ctrl-Right have the caret jump to the end of the word instead of the end of the string (from `[here]WORD,` to `WORD[here],` instead of `[here]WORD,` to `WORD,[here]`)

Any help?